# How can I cluster 3-dimensional data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, data-mining, fuzzy-c-means

For a project in my data mining class, I am to perform fuzzy-c means clustering on a data set, where each data point has 3 axes (I googled and that's apparently the correct way to pluralize 'axis'). I'm not exactly sure how I would do so, especially given the clustering algorithm I'm using. Here's an example of the data set I'm using;

| - | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| banana | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| carrot | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| durian | 6 | 7 | 1 |
| eggplant | 0 | 3 | 6 |

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!